# Docker container with webpack and volume does not save files into host from container volume. Just empty folders

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have docker-compose file for serving several containers.

Main idea: build frontend app via webpack and then through volumes grant access to built files to nginx container. Unfrotunately, I tried many things (stumbled upon my missing knowledge about that volumes are attached when container is starting but not building) and my current setup looks like this:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - '10040:80'
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
        - './docker/app/src:/app/src'
        - './docker/app/dist:/app/dist'
        - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./app.dockerfile
    entrypoint: ./app-build-dev.sh
    volumes:
        - './docker/app/src:/app/src/:rw'
        - './docker/app/dist:/app/dist/:rw'
        - './docker/app/node_modules:/app/node_modules/:rw'
```

Here is dockerfile for app.dockerfile

```
FROM "node"

COPY . /build-dir

WORKDIR /build-dir

RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -rf dist
```

Here is my script for webpack container (app-build-dev.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /build-dir


# echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /app/src"
# ls -la /app/src

# echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /app/src/js/app"
# ls -la /app/src/js/app

npm i
npm run build-dev

echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /build-dir"
ls -la /build-dir

echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /build-dir/src"
ls -la /build-dir/src

echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /build-dir/dist"
ls -la /build-dir/dist

# echo "Checking index.html built"
# cat /build-dir/dist/index.html

echo "Copying everything into /app so it can be shared with nginx"
cp -R /build-dir/* /app/*

echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /app/src"
ls -la /app/src

echo "CHECKING INNARDS OF /app/dist"
ls -la /app/dist

echo "Done"
```

As you can see I tried somehow to trick volumes since if I would work directly in the volumes (in /app in the container) - webpack would not even find needed files and save corrupted one file for index.html with message that there is no such file. But that's kinda offtop.

Anyway, I build inside /build-dir and then copy to mounted volume folder inside container, so it would be mirrored to host machine (and then can be used by nginx container).

What I get from that .sh script. Everything is fine except /app/dist dir is empty in container (/src is copied kind fine)

And on my host machine I have all the mounted folders but... empty. Nothing. Files are just not there.

Am I missing general conception here?

Thanks!